# Proper permission and directoy location for Git Version Control

Tags: git, version-control, file-permissions

I am using Git Version Control on an remote server and I have set up a repository that multiple people will be using to push/fetch from. I have put the repo under

```
/srv/subdir/git/.git
```

I have been experiencing problem after problem it seems like.

a) Is this location suitable for handling a project that will need to be accessed/modified by multiple developers and a designer? Or is there a better location?

b)Do I need to modify the permissions on the subdir/ and git/ directories in order to allow remote access? If I do what is the appropriate permissions I should allow?

I know this is a faily long request/question, but unfortunately like many other topics with well covered documentation, documentation does not always cover best practices.

I would appreciate anybodies advice and suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a: I prefer something like /git/repo.git, buts is down to preference.....

b: You may want to look at something like gitosis:

http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way

But also you can do the following:

```
mkdir repo.git
cd repo.git
git --bare init --shared=group
chgrp -R GROUP .
```

Where GROUP would be a group all your committers are in (like git or committers or developers), they should then be able to push into the repo.

Comment: Thank you? So would this take care of trying to push/fetch remotely?

Comment: I tried this and it told me invalid group after the last command

Comment: Did you run "chgrp -R GROUP" or "chgrp -R A_REAL_GROUP", GROUP should be somelike "git" or "committers" or whatever group name you want to use, and yes you can push via ssh into this repo assuming the push comes from someone in the right group.